# Magento 1.9 API - how to get sales of product from orders?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales, soap-api-v1

Trying to get some information about products sales based on SKU.
How can I do it ?

Do I have to pull all data orders then loop it trough or can I ask for sale of specified product directly ?

What I would like to achieve is: how many of SKUXXXX was sold within last month.
Is it possible via API ?
(hope it is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Magento's official API reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/sales.html), I don't think that the current core API can achieve your demand.

The solution is to extend/create another endpoint based on the existing API. These are some useful tutorial:

[Dev Docs of Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html)

[Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/extending-the-magento-api/)